# Rails response.should be_success is never true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, httpresponse

I am following Michael Hartl's excellent tutorial on Ruby on Rails. I'm stuck trying to understand the way **ActionDispatch::Response** works. This derives from Exercise 9 of Chapter 9 (Rails version 3.2.3).

In particular we're asked to make sure that the *admin* user is unable to `User#destroy` himself. I have an idea how to do that, but since I'm trying to follow a TDD methodology, I'm first writing the tests.

This is the relevant snippet in my test:

```rb
describe "authorization" do
    describe "as non-admin user" do
        let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
        let(:non_admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

        before{valid_signin non_admin}

        describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
            before do
                delete user_path(admin)
                #puts response.message
                puts response.succes?
            end
            specify{ response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
            specify{ response.should_not be_success }
        end
    end
    #Exercise 9.6-9 prevent admin from destroying himself
    describe "as admin user" do
        let(:admin){FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
        let(:non_admin){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

        before do 
            valid_signin admin
        end
        it "should be able to delete another user" do
            expect { delete user_path(non_admin) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
        end

        describe "can destroy others" do
            before do 
                puts admin.admin?
                delete user_path(non_admin)
                puts response.success?
            end
            #specify{response.should be_success}
            specify{response.should_not be_redirect}
        end 

        describe "cannot destroy himself" do
            before do
                delete user_path(admin)
                puts response.success?
            end
            #specify{response.should_not be_success}
            specify{response.should be_redirect}
        end 
    end

.
.
.
end
```

All the tests pass except the `"can destroy others"` test.

**However**, if I `puts response.success?` after every `delete` request, I always get `False`, so none of the requests "succeed".

Manually interacting with the webapp and deleting users works just fine, so I assume that `response.success` does not mean that the `detroy`(or whatever request for that matter) was not successful, but something else. I read it has to do with the difference between *HTTP responses 200/302/400*, but I'm not totally sure.

For the record, this is my `User#destroy`:

```rb
def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success]="User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
end
```

Any light on this?
thanks!

**Edit**

This is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:name){ |n| "Person #{n}" }
        sequence(:email){ |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
        password "foobar"
        password_confirmation "foobar"

        factory :admin do
            admin true
        end
    end

end
```

**Edit 2** as suggested by @Peter Alfvin, I changed lines

```
let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
```

to

```
let(:admin){FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
```

And all `user` to `admin` in general. I also added a `puts admin.admin?` before the `delete` request. Still not working!

**Edit 3**

Changing the test `"can destroy others"` as:

```rb
describe "can destroy others" do
  before do 
    puts admin.admin?
    delete user_path(non_admin)
    puts response.success?
  end

  #specify{response.should be_success}
  specify{response.should_not be_redirect}

end
```

Does not seem to help either.

Comment: The solution to my problem can be found at the follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19013924/1338339

Answer (score 1):

For your "admin" case, you're still creating and logging in as a "regular" user instead of an admin user, which is why you can't destroy anyone else.

Comment: I thought that was the problem. But I changed it to `:admin`, and it's not working either. See also my factory, last edit.

Comment: That's the thing about having multiple errors, you often can't confirm the existence of any one error by fixing it. :-) If you look at the examples in https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/master/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb, they confirm both this answer and the comment in the other answer from @AlexanderClark about `redirect_to`. :-)

Comment: I adapted the code to Rails 3.2 (this version's github has no answer to this exercise), using `expect{delete user_path(non_admin)}.to change(:User,:count).by(-1)`, but it fails. I can't seem to spot the other multiple errors. thanks!

Comment: What does your `User#destroy` method look like?

Comment: Oh, it's not `change(:User,...)` it's `change(User,...)`.  You're specifying the class whose `count` value is changing.

Comment: I would have thought you'd get an `undefined method -- count` error if you used `change(:User,...)`.  What _did_ you get in the way of an error with that?

Comment: that was a typo! I actually used `change(User,...)`. And the error is  `count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0`

Comment: Ok, so what does your `User#destroy` method look like?

Comment: it's at the end of my original question! :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the reference to `User#destroy` in your question.  Isn't that `UsersController#destroy`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37979/discussion-between-vint-i-vuit-and-peter-alfvin)

Answer (score 1):

response.success does indeed refer to the HTTP response code. By default, I believe this is anything in the 200 range. redirect_to is in the 300 range.

Comment: Then, does that mean that I shouldn't test it like that?

Comment: Yes. If an action redirects, `response.should redirect_to` takes the place of `response.should be_success`. You could say `response.should be_redirect`, but that would be redundant if you also tested `redirect_to`

Comment: it seems that checking that `response.should_not be_redirect` fails. And, considering that this is an `admin` deleting a `non-admin`, it should *not* be a redirect, right? See edit 3

Comment: @vint-i-vuit If you check out the file in github, you'll see that it uses a combination of `flash[:success].should =~ /destroyed/i` and `response.should redirect_to(users_path)`.

Comment: The last line of User#destroy redirects to users_path unless that has been updated.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: However if I `expect { delete user_path(non_admin) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)` that fails. Shouldn't it pass? I am sure that my user is logged in and has `admin:true`, as can be seen via `puts admin.admin?`.  Also, the question of what `response.success?` actually means is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user Factory includes this line

```
factory :user do
  #your user factory code
  factory :admin do 
    admin true
  end
end
```

Then `FactoryGirl.create(:admin)` will return an admin user or you can also use `user.toggle!(:admin)` which will switch a standard user to an admin user.

try this then

```
describe "as admin user" do
    let(:admin){FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
    let(:non_admin){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

    before do 
        valid_signin admin
    end
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
        expect { delete user_path(non_admin) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "can destroy others" do  #
        before do 
            puts admin.admin?
            delete user_path(non_admin)
            puts response.success?
        end
        #specify{response.should be_success}
        specify{response.should_not be_redirect}
    end 

    it "cannot destroy himself" do
        before do
            delete user_path(admin)
            puts response.success?
        end
        #specify{response.should_not be_success}
        specify{response.should be_redirect}
    end 
end
```

describe creates a magic Class it becomes a subClass of the describe class from my understanding. Rails has a lot of this magic and it can get confusing. Also I have not seen your controller but what are you expecting to happen when you destroy a user because if you followed the tutorial then there will be a redirect `delete` sent through the browser will call your `destroy` method in the `UsersController` which in the tutorial has this line `redirect_to users_url` so `response.should_not be_redirect` will always fail because the spec is wrong not the controller.