# Rspec similar code for testing DELETE request gives different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Following Michael Hartl's book on Ruby on Rails, I can't seem to understand why one of the tests pass and another fails, considering they do mostly the same. This derives from testing `UsersController#destroy` from Exercise 9.6-9.

This is my `spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb`:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

    subject { page }
    describe "index" do
        let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        #before/after ALL TESTS, not USERS
        before(:all){ 30.times {FactoryGirl.create(:user) }}
        after(:all) {User.delete_all}

        #before EACH TEST, no user
        before(:each) do
            valid_signin user
            visit users_path
        end

        describe "delete links" do
            it { should_not have_link('delete') }
            describe "as an admin user" do
                let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
                let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
                before do
                    valid_signin admin
                    visit users_path
                end
                it "should be able to delete another user" do
                    expect { delete user_path(user) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
                end
.
.
.
end
```

And this is my `spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb`:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "AuthenticationPages" do
    subject{ page }
    describe "signin page" do
        before { visit signin_path }
        it { should have_selector('h1',text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
    end
    describe "signin" do
        before { visit signin_path }

        #INVALID INFO
        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Sign in"}

            it{ should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in')}
            #it{ should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')}
            it{ should have_error_message('Invalid')}

            describe "after visiting another page" do
                before { click_link "Home" }
                #it{ should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error')}
                it{ should_not have_error_message()}
                #exercise 9.6-3
                it{ should_not have_link('Profile')}
                it{ should_not have_link('Settings')}
            end
        end

        #VALID INFO
        describe "with valid information" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
            before{ valid_signin(user) }

            it{ should have_selector('title', text: user.name)}
            it{ should have_link('Users', href: users_path)}
            it{ should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user))}
            it{should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user))}
            it{ should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path)}
            it{ should_not have_selector('Sign in', href:signin_path)}

            describe "followed by signout" do
                before{click_link "Sign out"}
                it{ should have_link('Sign in') }
            end
            #Exercise 9.6-6
            describe "accessing new and create actions" do
                describe "through website" do
                    before{visit signup_path}
                    it{ should_not have_selector('h1',text:"Sign up")} 
                    it{ should_not have_button("Create my account")} 
                end
                describe "through a POST request" do
                    before { post users_path}
                    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path)}
                end
            end
        end
    end
    describe "authorization" do
        describe "as non-admin user" do
            let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
            let(:non_admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

            before{valid_signin non_admin}

            #Check that loggin to nonadmin works(debug ex.9.6-9)
            describe "should render the non-admin profile page" do
                it{ should have_selector('title', text: non_admin.name)}
            end

            describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
                before do
                    delete user_path(admin)
                    #puts response.message
                    #puts response.success?
                end
                specify{ response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
                specify{ response.should_not be_success }
            end
        end
        #Exercise 9.6-9 prevent admin from destroying himself
        describe "as admin user" do
            let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            let(:admin){FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
            let(:non_admin){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

            before do 
                valid_signin admin
                visit users_path
            end
            it "should be able to delete another user" do
                expect { delete user_path(user) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
            end

.
.
.
end
```

I know from interacting with the application that deleting users *does* work, the problem is with testing it.The test of interest here is the one described as **"should be able to delete another user"**, which is the same in both files `user_pages_spec.rb` and `authentication_pages_spec.rb`.

There's two things I cannot seem to understand:

1. At `user_pages_spec.rb` the test with `expect { delete user_path(user) }.to change(User,:count).by(-1)` *does* pass, however if I change it to `expect { delete user_path(non_admin) }.to change(User,:count).by(-1)`, it fails. Why is that? They are both created with the same factory parameters.
2. Why is the test in the `authentication_pages_spec.rb` never passing? No matter whether it's `user_path(user)` or `user_path(non_admin)`.

This is my factory:

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:name){ |n| "Person #{n}" }
        sequence(:email){ |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
        password "foobar"
        password_confirmation "foobar"

        factory :admin do
            admin true
        end
    end

end
```

Here my `users_controller.rb`:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
    before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_filter :admin_user, only: [:destroy]
    def new
        #change for exercise 9.6-6
        if signed_in?
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            @user=User.new
        end
    end
    def show
        @user=User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def create
        if signed_in?
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            @user = User.new(params[:user])
            if @user.save
                sign_in @user
                flash[:success]="Welcome to the Sample App!"
                # Handle a successful save.
                redirect_to @user
            else
                render 'new'
            end
        end
    end

    def edit
        #@user= User.find(params[:id]) <----we can delete this because the before filter correct_user now defines @user variable
    end

    def update
        #@user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            # Handle a successful update.
            flash[:success]="Profile updated"
            sign_in @user
            redirect_to @user
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def index
        #@users= User.all
        @users= User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def destroy
        puts "The current user is:"+current_user.name
            puts "Is user admin?:"+current_user.admin.to_s
            User.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success]="User destroyed."
        redirect_to users_path
    end

    private
    def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
            store_location
            redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
        end
    end

    def correct_user
        @user =User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

And the model  `user.rb`:

```rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  before_save { self.email.downcase! }
  #callback for session token generation
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  #validates :password, presence: true, length:{minimum:6}
  validates :password, length:{minimum:6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true


  private
    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token=SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

This is the support file where `valid_signin` is defined:

```rb
include ApplicationHelper
def valid_signin(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end

def valid_signup(user)
    fill_in "Name", with: user.name
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password_confirmation
    #click_button "Sign in"
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
    match do |page|
        page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
    end
end
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_success_message do |message|
    match do |page|
        page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: message)
    end
end
```

"
Note to others: This is a follow-on to [Rails response.should be_success is never true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990403/rails-response-should-be-success-is-never-true)
"

**Edit**

This is the `SessionsHelper`( spec/helpers/sessions_helper.rb):

```rb
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token]=user.remember_token
        current_user=user
    end
    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end

    def current_user?(user)
        user == current_user
    end

    def sign_out
        current_user=nil
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end
    def redirect_back_or(default)
        redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
        session.delete(:return_to)
    end
    def store_location
        session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    end

end
```

**EDIT 2** Added `puts` to `UsersController#destroy`.

This is the output for the different test running:

rspec on `spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb` trying to delete `user`:

```rb
..The current user is: Person 35
Is user admin?: true
..

Finished in 8.16 seconds
4 examples, 0 failures
```

rspec on `spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb` trying to delete `non_admin`:

```rb
The current user is: Person 35
Is user admin?: true
F.

Failures:

  1) User pages index delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
     Failure/Error: expect { delete user_path(non_admin) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
       count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

rspec on `spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb` trying to delete either `user` or `non_admin`:

```rb
Run options: include {:full_description=>/(?-mix:as\ admin\ user)/}
The current user is: Person 1
Is user admin?: true
FThe current user is: Person 3
Is user admin?: true
FThe current user is: Person 5
Is user admin?: true
.

Failures:

  1) AuthenticationPages authorization as admin user should be able to delete another user
     Failure/Error: expect { delete user_path(user) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
       count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:99:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm still not sure why it does it three times, one for each `let(...)`?

## Final Edit

See solution as last answer.

Comment: Without seeing any of your actual model or controller code, how is someone supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: You might want to show `current_user` as well.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question, the difference between `user` and `non-admin` is that you logged in as `user` in the outer `describe` block. If your subsequent attempt to log-in as `admin` is failing and you remain logged in as `user`, that would explain the behavior you're seeing. You haven't provided the definition of `valid_signin`, but if it doesn't work independent of whether you are already signed in and have navigated to the sign in page, then this would explain what's going on.

Similarly, your `authentication_pages_spec.rb` examples rely entirely on `valid_signin` working successfully. While you haven't logged in previously in this example, you haven't done any navigation either, so if `valid_signin` is a simple form fill-in (as it was defined in the 3.2 version of the tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2), then that would explain why it's failing in this case.

As an aside, if you're mixing 3.2 code snippets with 4.0 code snippets, you're going to encounter a lot of problems.

Note to others: This is a follow-on to [Rails response.should be_success is never true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990403/rails-response-should-be-success-is-never-true)

Comment: Thank you for the reply( again :) ). I added the `valid_signin` helper definition at the end of the post. Plus some of the navigation tests that I execute, which all pass. Regarding the singing-in of `user` before the describe block, I certainly do that but in the `user_pages_spec.rb` case, and that one does work! But I do not do it in the `authentication_pages_spec.rb`(signing in before), and it doesn't work!

Comment: Given the definition you posted, it doesn't seem to me that `valid_signin` will work if you're already logged in. Does it to you?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However the case I do *re*-login is the `user_pages_spec.rb`, and in that case the test *does* pass. Shouldn't it be the opposite way, considering your point?

Comment: It depends. My understanding from what you said is that the test for `user_pages_spec.rb` only works if you're trying to delete `user` (i.e. the already logged in user) and not if you're trying to delete some other user. I realize that your controller before filter for `delete` is all about the `admin` option, so this shouldn't be allowed either, but it is odd.

Comment: Have you tried putting in print statements to figure out what's going on? Is it the `admin_user` before filter that is always kicking in? In any event, what is the value of `current_user` at that point?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. So I will try making a helper to force signing-out before signing-in. Because otherwise I `valid_singin` twice in a row. Although indeed, I tried to `puts current_user.admin?` and it looked coherent as I recalled. So I assumed that `valid_signin` twice in a row was also signing-out implicitly. I will explore this again, thanks!

Comment: If `current_user.admin?` is really `true` for the failing tests, then that begs the question of what's going on in the body of the `destroy` method, which you would need to check as well.

Comment: I cannot call `puts current_user` or `puts current_user.admin`, without including `include SessionsHelper` in the `user_pages_spec.rb`. However if I include it and run it, I get `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:16:in `current_user': undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<Class:0x0000000516dcd0> (NameError)`. I figure `spec` by design is not supposed to call these methods? I'm kind of lost now...

Comment: I was talking about adding the `puts current_user...` calls to your `controller`, not to your spec.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, sorry. I just edited it with the results of `puts` at the `UsersController#destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently I managed to solve the issue. The root of the problem was that `let(...)` is **lazily evaluated**, which means that "*it is not evaluated until the first time
the method it defines is invoked.*". Documentation [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).

Instead, `let!(..:)` can be used to force its evaluation. I have to thank **NemesisD** at the channel **#rubyonrails** for pointing this out, and also **Peter Alfvin** here on Stackoverflow.

The final code with tests passing looks like(see change from `let` to `let!`):

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "AuthenticationPages" do
    subject{ page }
    describe "signin page" do
        before { visit signin_path }
        it { should have_selector('h1',text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign in')) }
    end
    describe "signin" do
        before { visit signin_path }

        #INVALID INFO
        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Sign in"}

            it{ should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in')}
            #it{ should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')}
            it{ should have_error_message('Invalid')}

            describe "after visiting another page" do
                before { click_link "Home" }
                #it{ should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error')}
                it{ should_not have_error_message()}
                #exercise 9.6-3
                it{ should_not have_link('Profile')}
                it{ should_not have_link('Settings')}
            end
        end

        #VALID INFO
        describe "with valid information" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
            before{ valid_signin(user) }

            it{ should have_selector('title', text: user.name)}
            it{ should have_link('Users', href: users_path)}
            it{ should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user))}
            it{should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user))}
            it{ should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path)}
            it{ should_not have_selector('Sign in', href:signin_path)}

            describe "followed by signout" do
                before{click_link "Sign out"}
                it{ should have_link('Sign in') }
            end
            #Exercise 9.6-6
            describe "accessing new and create actions" do
                describe "through website" do
                    before{visit signup_path}
                    it{ should_not have_selector('h1',text:"Sign up")} 
                    it{ should_not have_button("Create my account")} 
                end
                describe "through a POST request" do
                    before { post users_path}
                    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path)}
                end
            end
        end
    end
    describe "authorization" do
        describe "as non-admin user" do
            let(:admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
            let(:non_admin) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

            before{valid_signin non_admin}

            #Check that loggin to nonadmin works(debug ex.9.6-9)
            describe "should render the non-admin profile page" do
                it{ should have_selector('title', text: non_admin.name)}
            end

            describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
                before do
                    delete user_path(admin)
                    #puts response.message
                    #puts response.success?
                end
                specify{ response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
                specify{ response.should_not be_success }
            end
        end
        #Exercise 9.6-9 prevent admin from destroying himself
        describe "as admin user" do
            let!(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            let!(:admin){FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}
            let!(:non_admin){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

            before{ valid_signin admin }

            it "should be able to delete another user" do
                expect { delete user_path(user) }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
            end

.
.
.
end
```